# How can I get the value from this variable inside function?

Tags: javascript, node.js

I'm novice with javascript and I really don't know how can I get the "networks" value.

```
scanner.scan(function(error, networks){
   if(error) {
        console.error(error);
    } else {
        console.log(networks); << print the correct value
    }
});
console.log(networks) << print undefined
```

I just want to use "networks" outside function

Anyone could help me? Thanks!

Comment: is scan function asynchronous ?

Comment: Your second `console.log(networks)` its out of the scope

Comment: @dato, yeah, it is

Comment: @YosvelQuintero, yep, I know that, but how can I use "networks" outside function?

Comment: Reliably you cannot.

Comment: If  `networks` variable is not previously defined, it will be hoisted, so that's why you get `undefined`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add a variable before the scan function and set the value inside the function:

```
var netValue = null;
scanner.scan(function(error, networks){
   netValue = networks;
   if(error) {
      console.error(error);
    } else {
      console.log(networks); << print the correct value
    }
});
console.log(netValue);
```

The final line still may not work though if the `scanner.scan()` function is an asynchronous call.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a global value networks, and update that from within the scan function:

```
var globalNetworks;

scanner.scan(function(error, networks){
    globalNetworks = networks;
    if(error) {
      console.error(error);
    } else {
      console.log(networks); << print the correct value
    }
});
console.log(networks) << print the correct value
```

I suggest that you read about how scope works in javascript:
http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_scope.asp

Answer (score 0):

The reason you cannot get the value of `networks` is because it is wrapped in a closure, the value is only available inside that function.
Go here to read more about closures:

[How do JavaScript closures work?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/111102/how-do-javascript-closures-work)

To have access to it outside you can create another variable outside of the function and set that to variable to `network` inside the function:

```
var otherNetworks;
scanner.scan(function(error, networks){
   otherNetworks = networks;
   if(error) {
      console.error(error);
    } else {
      console.log(networks); << print the correct value
    }
   });
 console.log(otherNetworks) << print correctValue
```

Comment: I already did it before, but it is only showing the global value, the variable is updated inside fuction, but does not persist its value outside.

Comment: I highly doubt that, can you reproduce that in jsfiddle or jsbin?

Answer (score 0):

I already did it before, but it is only showing the global value:

```
var globalNetworks = "global"
var scanner = wifiscanner();

    scanner.scan(function(error, networks){
      globalNetworks = networks;
      console.log(globalNetworks) //displaying all the wlan0 networks available
      if(error) {
        console.error(error);
      } else {
        // console.log(networks);
      }
    });

    console.log(globalNetworks) // displaying global
```

btw, networks is a json